# Dateadd not working on Power BI when doing comparative analysis

Tags: powerbi

So, I am trying to create a comparative analysis. I created a measure to calculate the sum of all the entries of different categories and called it Total, and then I used another measure, DRE, to show me either the value of the categorie or the sum of the previous values, if it is a subtotal, this is the DAX formula:

`DRE =  SWITCH( SELECTEDVALUE('Chave de Modelo'[A ou ST]), "A", [Total], "ST", CALCULATE( [Total], FILTER( ALL('Chave de Modelo'), 'Chave de Modelo'[Cont. DRE] < MAX('Chave de Modelo'[Cont. DRE]) ) ) )`

A is not a subtotal an ST is a subtotal.

Alright, then I used another measure to calculate the values of the previous month, this one:

`DRE LM = CALCULATE( 'Base DRE Evo'[DRE], DATEADD('Calendario'[Mês BI],-1,MONTH))` 
Calendário here is my date dable and Mês BI is my date colum.

The problem is that when I put these two measures on my matrix the values of the DRE LM (previous month) is exactly the same value as the one of the current month (DRE). I do not know why this is happening. I tried to use PREVIOUSMONTH as well but it didn't work, instead of the value of the DRE, the DRE LM had only blanks. I did exactly the same as I saw on a video and on another file from my company but only here it did't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

I was expecting to have the values of both months.